# Spring MVC custom url-pattern

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have configured Spring Security but it can't work.

My web.xml

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/security-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring Security filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I defined DispatcherServlet's url-pattern / , it works fine . 
But when I change it to /spring/* , although I configed filter-mapping's url-pattern both of /* and /spring/* , it can't work

In this case what can I do ? Please tell me

Comment: What doesn't work? Also why are you loading your application twice? (Both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` are loading the `dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml` effectivly loading everything twice (which will eventually lead to interesting issues).

Comment: Oh , I don'nt know that will load my application twice. I'm a beginner to Spring MVC.Thank you so much

Back to my question , I mean it can load DispatcherServlet and SecurityConfig . But when I do a post to /login URL , it can't login ( error 405 : method not allow ) 

But when I change dispatcherservlet's url-pattern to "/" , it can login and redirect to my homepage normally

Comment: Then there must be something in  your configuration that prohibits that. Bu tyou haven't included that in your question.